# How to deal with "it doesn't match" or "it matches"

Tags: discussion

I've answered many regex questions. The recent one being [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324639/generic-regex-that-support-the-formats-given/23324688).

OP hasn't given any rules for regex. So I provided him a relaxed regex. And a user commented it doesn't match this or that.

Surely my regex matches what OP asks for, and I'll provide stricter regex, if OP was worried about it. But in this case, he isn't.

So, how should I deal with these comments? (*I've currently addressed commentor's issues*)

Comment: See [Exit Strategies for Chameleon Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, OP hasn't changed his question. It is another user who is commenting me on that

Comment: In the example you gave, I feel the question was implicitly clear that it would *not* want `1....` and `1,,,,,` to match, and hence was not wat the OP (implicitly) asked for. (Or are you only referring to the number of spaces?)

Comment: Maybe not in the question, but isn't he asking for additional help in the comments?  This is an inherent problem with `icanhazregexez` questions; they are always very specific, but the OP doesn't provide the necessary specificity in the original question to make it reasonably answerable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, no mate. All comments to my answer are from a different user

Comment: No, @RobertHarvey, I was confused when you just commented *Another user? Who cares?*. I thought whether I was wrong or the commenter to my question. But after edit, it got solved ;)

Comment: Sounds like it worked out OK then.  Note that, if a regex is matching something the OP didn't specify, a stricter regex would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Questions like this should be closed as **unclear what you're asking**. If the question is not specific enough for you to know *exactly* what the asker wants the regular expression to match, then s/he has not provided enough details for you to sufficiently answer the question.

You could first ask the OP to clarify using comments: if a sufficient amount of time has passed without an edit or a follow-up comment, you should vote to close as **unclear what you're asking** or **too broad**.